# Why are the germs of holomorphic functions semi-local?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-geometry

It certainly contains a maximal idea $\{f \in \mathscr{O}_n|f(0)= 0\}$ which satisfies the property that elements outside this ideal are units. However, Why is it the unique maximal ideal of $\mathscr{O}_n$?

Comment: By "semi local" you mean "unique maximal ideal (but not necessarily noetherian")?  Nowadays "semilocal" is often used for commutative rings to mean "has finitely many maximal ideals."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your ideal $M_1$. If $M_2$ is a maximal ideal distinct from $M_1$, then there exists $x\in M_2\setminus M_1$.

But you just posited that elements outside of $M_1$ are units, so $M_2$ contains a unit, and $M_2$ is therefore the entire ring. A contradiction.